# Selenium Functions Missing Unable To use them

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
import sys

#op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#op.add_argument('headless')


def print_same_line(text):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    

class Join:
    def join_link():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://meetingsapac29.webex.com/meet/pr1566903906")
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(4)
        click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="push_download_join_by_browser"]')
        click.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        
        input_name = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="meetingSimpleContainer"]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
        input_name.clear()
        input_name.send_keys(Name)
        
        

        input_email = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="meetingSimpleContainer"]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
        input_email.clear()
        input_email.send_keys(Email)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = ["Rutul","Satyajit","Swaraj"]
    email = ["rutulkmr10@gmail.com","Satyajit2003@gmail.com","Swaraj12@gmail.com"]
    Name = random.choice(name)
    Email = random.choice(email)
    Join.join_link()
```

**Error:**

```
File "webhook.py", line 44, in <module>
    Join.join_link()
  File "webhook.py", line 29, in join_link
    input_name.clear()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'clear'
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

**This error is blowing my nerves**
**If anyone has any idea how to resolve this Please Help**
selenium Keys.py doesn't have any function as Clear, send_keys, etc.
everything is working good but when it comes to send_keys and clear function it shows the about error!
please help if anyone knows a solution for this.

Comment: Why are you using `lambda` in statement of finding xpath??

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
box.send_keys("aabb")
box.clear()
```

lambda:  a function, this func not be called. You assign a function to a variable, del lambda: and try again.